# Result in past simple

Tags: past-tense

I was thinking a lot about result in **present perfect**, but when I reed a book, that character appeared just a moment ago (recently) they still use **past simple** (for example, "Why did it take you so long?"), but when something happened recently we use **present perfect**. I think that **past simple** is used to just show the past action that has finished and has the result but we ignore the result. Maybe I'm wrong but when I see past simple sentence (without *ago*, 2 minutes ago, etc.)

Or something like "I forgot" - result she doesn't have or did something, but we ignore it and just show the past action.

"I've forgotten" - is more like we have a result, like we don't have something or  did something

What do you think? Is it a good approach to the case?

Comment: Yes. If I understand your meaning right, that is one of the  major differences between past simple and present perfect.   https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-simple-past-and-present-perfect/2752310.html  says exactly that: 'The present perfect confuses English learners because it refers to a past action. It is also called “present perfect” because **speakers use it to stress the importance of a past event in the present**. The sentence “I have graduated from college,” emphasizes the present effect of a past event -- graduation.'

Comment: It is also true that some English speakers aren't always consistent about these tenses and sometimes use the simple past even when the present perfect might be more appropriate. E.g. "Oops! I've forgotten my wallet!". (Past event with effects felt in the present.) In the same circumstance, someone else might just as likely say, "Oops! I forgot my wallet!"

Comment: Good to know that I'm right. I want to ask you what about books ? Does they keep the grammar rules (more often than the movies ?). I want to get used to those tenses, and prevent any problem in future. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: I just meant that the choice betw simple past and present perfect is not a clear-cut thing. It depends on the speaker's (or writer's) attitude toward the topic: some people may choose one tense, & others a different one. I didn't mean to say that we just ignore the rules of English. (E.g.: past tense of "take" = "took"; nobody violates that one, except as a slip of the tongue.) Of course people are "sloppier" in speech than writing (especially in *books*). But even in writing, the usage of simple past/present perfect can vary.